# AWK script to process information spread over multiple file lines

Tags: awk

I am trying to do a text processing script, for what seems to be a rather simple task.
I have a file, which contains the following repeated pattern

```
111 0 1000 other stuff        #<- here a new element begins
      some text &             #<- "&" or white spaces increment - 
      some more               #<- signal continue on next line
      last line 
221 1 1.22E22                 # new element $2!=0 must be followed by float
   text &
   contiuned text
c comment line in between 
   more text &
last line
2221 88 -12.123 &
line1 
   line2
c comment line 
last line
223 0 lll -111        $ element given by line 
22 22 -3.14           $ element given by new line
```

I would like to get

```
111 0 1000 other stuff        #<- here a new element begins
      some text &             #<- "&" or white spaces increment - 
      some more               #<- signal continue on next line
      last line &
             xyz=1 
221 1 1.22E22                 # new element $2!=0 must be followed by float
   text &
   contiuned text
c comment line in between 
   more text &
last line &
      xyz=1
2221 88 -12.123 &
line1 
   line2
c comment line 
last line &
      xyz=1 
223 0 lll -111 &     $ element given by line
      xyz=1 
22 22 -3.14 &          $ element given by new line
      xyz=1
```

I would like to develop an `awk` script that appends a string to the `last line` of each element. To do so my script looks for the new element pattern, and continues to read until one of the next element indicators are found. Unfortunately, it does not function properly because it prints the last line two times and fails to append to the very last line of the file.

```
function newelement(line) {
  split(line, s, " ")
  if (s[1] ~/^[0-9]+$/ && ((s[2] ~/^[0-9]+$/ && s[3] ~/\./) || (s[2] == 0 && s[3] !~/\./))) {
    return 1
  } else {
    return -1
  }
}

function contline(line) {
  if (line~/&/ || line~/^[cC]/ || line~/^\s{3,10}[^\s]./) {
    return 1
  } else {
    return -1
  }
}

BEGIN {
  subs = " xyz=1 "
} #increment to have the next line in store
FNR == 1 {
  getline nextline < FILENAME
} 
{ 
  # get the next line
  getline nextline < FILENAME
  if (newelement($0) == 1 && NR < 3673) {
    if (length(old) > 0 || $0~/^$/) {
      printf("%s &\n%20s\n", old, subs)
      print $0
    } 
    # to capture one line elements with no following continuation
    # i.e.
    # 221 91 0.5 33333
    # 22  0  11
    #look at the next line
    else if (($0!~/&/ && contline(nextline) == -1)) {
      printf("%s &\n%20s\n", $0, subs)
    }
  } 
  else {
  print "-" $0
  }
  # store last not - commented line
  if ($0!~/^\s{0,20}[cC]/) old = $0

}
```

Where the comment line has `c` or `c` followed by an empty space. Comment lines should be preserved but no strings should be appended to them.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, `N` was a typo. I included the requested output

Comment: Yes, that is my problem.  I am also not able to append to the last line of the last element. The `& \n xyz=1` is missing there.

Comment: Ah lord, You need the expected output. That is the actual wrong output. I will correct it ok

Comment: It seems to me you wanted to skip those comment `c/C` lines, but above expected output 3rd line there is one, do you want it or not?

Comment: Yes. Yes the final outcome should be the same file with just  `& \n xyz=1` appended to the last line of each element

Comment: Then what about the `-`s?

Comment: I keep everything from the original file as it is and just append `& \n xyz=1`

Comment: Is it possible the comment be the last of one block? -- If so how to deal with it?

Comment: Comments can appear anywhere. They should be preserved, but appending something to them is not allowed. Therefore I keep the last uncommented line and append only to it.

Comment: @AlexanderCska  What about empty lines? preserve? append? ignore?

Comment: @Tiw there are no empty lines. Once the first empty line comes, the data block ends and plane text begins. For that part I do simple `print $0`  I also improved my script.

Comment: @AlexanderCska what if a line with a trailing `&` is followed by a line matching `newelement()`?

Comment: @jxc that is not allowed.

Comment: @AlexanderCska please check if the code logic I implemented works for your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the following code and let me know if it works for you:

```
$ cat 3.1.awk
BEGIN{
    subs      = " xyz=1 "
    threshold = 3673
}

# return boolean if the current line is a new element
function is_new_element(){
    return ($1~/^[0-9]+$/) && (($2 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && $3~/\./) || ($2 == 0 && $3 !~/\./))
}

# return boolean if the current line is a comment or empty line
function is_comment() {
    return /^\s*[cC] / || /^\s*$/
}

# function to append extra text to line
# and followed by comments if applicable
function get_extra_text(     extra_text) {
    extra_text = sprintf("%s &\n%20s", prev, subs)
    text = (text ? text ORS : "") extra_text
    if (prev_is_comment) {
        text = text ORS comment
        prev_is_comment = 0
        comment = ""
    }
    return text
}

NR < threshold {
# replace the above line with the following one if 
# you want to process up to the first EMPTY line
#NR==1,/^\s*$/ {
    # if the current line is a new element
    if (is_new_element()) {
        # save the last line and preceeding comments 
        # into the variable 'text', skip the first new element
        if (has_hit_first_new_element) text = get_extra_text()
        has_hit_first_new_element = 1
        prev_is_new = 1
    # before hitting the first new_element line, all lines 
    # should be printed as-is
    } else if (!has_hit_first_new_element) {
        print
        next
    # if current line is a comment
    } else if (is_comment()) {
        comment = (comment ? comment ORS : "") $0
        prev_is_comment = 1
        next
    # if the current line is neither new nor comment
    } else {
        # if previous line a new element
        if (prev_is_new) {
            print (text ? text ORS : "") prev
            text = ""
        # if previous line is comment
        } else if (prev_is_comment) {
            print prev ORS comment
            prev_is_comment = 0
            comment = ""
        } else {
            print prev
        }
        prev_is_new = 0
    }
    # prev saves the last non-comment line
    prev = $0
    next
}
# print the last block if NR >= threshold 
!is_last_block_printed {
    print get_extra_text()
    is_last_block_printed = 1;
}

# print lines when NR > threshold or after the first EMPTY line
{   print "-" $0 }
```

**Where**

The lines are divided into 3 categories and processed differently:

1. `is_new_element()` to true when the current line is a new element, the flag `prev_is_new` identify the previous new element
2. `is_comment()` function to true, then the current line is a comment, `prev_is_comment` to identify the previous comment line
3. other lines: all other lines except the above two

**Others notes:**

- You can select a `NR < threshold`(which is 3673 in your code), or a range pattern `NR==1,/^\s*$/` to process only a range of lines.
- `is_last_block_printed` flag and related code are to make sure the last processing block is printed either at the end of the above range or in the `END{}` block
- I did not check the trailing `&` for the continuing line, if they are followed by a comment or a new element, the logic has to be defined, i.e. which one should take precedence
- If there are other lines before the first `is_new_element()` line, the code will not work well. This can be fixed by adding another flag instead of using `if (NR > 1)` to update `text`.

**Testing Sample:**

```
$ cat 3.1.txt
111 0 1000 other stuff        #<- here a new element begins
      some text &             #<- "&" or white spaces increment -
      some more               #<- signal continue on next line
      last line
221 1 1.22E22                 # new element $2!=0 must be followed by float
    text &
   contiuned text
c comment line in between
   more text &
last line
2221 88 -12.123 &
line1
   line2
c comment line 1
last line
c comment line 2
c comment line 3
c comment line 4
c comment line 5
223 0 lll -111        
223 0 22 -111        
223 0 22 -111        
c comment line in between 1
c comment line in between 2
22 22 -3.14         
c comment line at the end
```

**Output:**

```
$ awk -f 3.1.awk 3.1.txt
111 0 1000 other stuff        #<- here a new element begins
      some text &             #<- "&" or white spaces increment - 
      some more               #<- signal continue on next line
      last line  &
              xyz=1 
221 1 1.22E22                 # new element $2!=0 must be followed by float
   text &
   contiuned text
c comment line in between 
   more text &
last line &
              xyz=1 
2221 88 -12.123 &
line1 
   line2
c comment line 1
last line &
              xyz=1 
c comment line 2
c comment line 3
c comment line 4
c comment line 5
223 0 lll -111  &
              xyz=1 
223 0 22 -111  &
              xyz=1 
223 0 22 -111  &
              xyz=1 
c comment line in between 1
c comment line in between 2
22 22 -3.14    &
              xyz=1 
c comment line at the end
```

**Some extra explanantion:**

- One concern to process the text is the trailing newline "\n" when appending  `subs` to `prev` line. it's especially important when consecutive new_element lines happen.
- Important to notice, the variable `prev` in the code is defined as the previous non-comment line (category-1, 3 defined above). there could be zero or multiple comment (category-2) lines between the `prev` line and the current line. that's also why we use `print prev ORS comment` instead of `print comment ORS prev` when printing regular comments (not those preceding the new_element line).
- A block of `comment` lines (1 or more consecutive comment lines) are saved into the variable `comment`. if it's right before the new_element line, then append the block to the variable `text`. All other block of comments will be printed in the line `print prev ORS comment` mentioned above
- The function `get_extra_text()` is to process the extra_text, which is in the order:  `prev subs ORS comments`, where `comments` is appended only when `prev_is_comment` flag is `1`. Do notice that the same variable `text` could have saved multiple `prev subs ORS comments` blocks if there are consecutive new_element lines.
- We only `print` on the category-3 line mentioned above(neither a new_element nor a comment). This is a safe place when we have no worry about the trailing newline or extra_text:

  - if the prev_is_new, we print the cached `text` and then the variable prev (which is a new_element)
  - if the prev_is_comment, we just print the `prev ORS comment`. notice again the variable `prev` saves the last non-comment line from the current line, it does not have to be the line right above the current line.
  - all other case, just print the `prev` line as-is
- Since we are concatenating lines into `text` and `comment` variables, we use the following syntax to avoid the leading ORS (which is "\n" by default)

  `text = (text ? text ORS : "") prev`

  If the leading ORS is not a concern, you can just use the following:

  `text = text ORS prev`

  and because the lines are appended to these variables, we will need to reset 
  them (i.e. `text = ""`) each time after we consume them, otherwise, the 
  concatenated variable will contain all previously processed lines.

**Final notes**

1. added a flag `has_hit_first_new_element`, in case there are lines before the first new_element line, they will be printed as-is. In this code, the first new_element line should be treated differently, using NR==1 is not a safe-belt.
2. removed the code in the `END{}` block which is redundant

Comment: Thank you for your help, I will check it.

Comment: I checked your script and it works fine. Most importantly, I learned new features of AWK I was not aware of. One such feature is to match only a range of lines `NR==1,/^\s*$/`. Actually what is `print (text ? text ORS : "") prev text = ""` doing? Thank you for your help and for the time you took to help me with this issue.

Comment: @AlexanderCska, I added an new section `Some extra explanantion` in my post, please let me know if that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function newelement(line){
    split(line,s," ")
    if(s[1]~/^[0-9]+$/ && ((s[2]~/^[0-9]+$/ && s[3]~/\./)|| (s[2]==0 && s[3]!~/\./))){return 1}
    else{return -1}
}

BEGIN{
    subs=" xyz=1 "
} 
{
    if (length($0)==0) next   # Skip empty lines, remove or change it according to your needs.
    if (newelement($0)==1){
        if (length(last_data)>0) {
            printf("%s &\n%20s\n",last_data,subs)
            if (last_type=="c") {
                print comments
            }
        }
        last_data=$0
        last_type="i"
    } else if($0 ~/^\s*[cC] /) {
        if (last_type=="c") comments = comments ORS $0
        else comments = $0
        last_type="c"
    } else {
        if (last_type=="c") print comments
        else if(length(last_data)>0) print last_data
        last_data=$0
        last_type="d"
    }
}
END{
    printf("%s &\n%20s\n",last_data,subs)
    if (last_type=="c") print comments
}
```

Three variables:

- `last_data` to hold last data line.
- `last_type` to hold the type of last line, `i` for indicator, `c` for comments.
- `comments` to hold comments line(s).

Comment: This function stile does not get it right. It prints the repeated end line after the new element line.

Comment: @AlexanderCska Your explanation, and your comments, contradict with your own code.  If you would ask a question again, please try to be clear and with clear sample data and corresponding expected output.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience and really appreciate your help and the time you have dedicated to solving my problem. Unfortunately, although much better written, your code, still does not do it quite right. You removed the comment line symbol and now you append the string to any last line, may it be comment or real information line. The comment lines should be preserved, but real data should not be appended to them. Hence `$0 !~/^\s*[cC] / && newelement($0)==-1` in my code. It also fails to detect element lines that are not followed by continuation. I would update the example.

Comment: @AlexanderCska Updated the code, please try it again.

Comment: @Tim wow that seems to work. I will test it on the big file. Could you please check also, why my updated code keeps printing the last line twice. I would like to know my mistake.

Comment: @AlexanderCska Your code literally gives me headache... don't use `getline` like that, it will make the flow hard to trace and the logical unclear.  Pardon me I didn't and not going to finish reading your code :(

Comment: Your code still appends to comment lines if they are a single letter `c` on the entire line. This is also possible. Can be solved by `$0 ~/^\s*[cC]\s*/`

Comment: @AlexanderCska I used your own regex, you can improve/change it according to your situation. You didn't give clear or enough details about the definition of comments. Btw, I probably will stop update my answer here. And I suggest you stop changing your code in the question. Also try to give yourself some rest, after that use a pen and a piece of paper to draw the flow, this will make it clearer for you to finish your real code.

Comment: thank you for the help and I am sorry for the mixed up description, but it is not easy to explain all the features at once. I have one last question. Is it possible to modify the code, so that the END block is executed the first time empty line is met , print the new line and then just echo the input file. In my input the empty line is the beginning of another section, that I don't want to modify.

Comment: @AlexanderCska If it's only an empty line and it's guranteed after those lines then it's easy, move the `END` block to above the main block, and change the `END` to `/^$/`, add a signal varialbe eg `sign=1` inside. Add another block above them, `sign { print; next }`.